# restful-keystone and populate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a News and a User model in my KeystoneJS installation.The User model is the one produced by Keystone.

**News.js**

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var News = new keystone.List('News', {
autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
map: { name: 'title'},
defaultSort: '-publishedAt'
});

News.add({
title: { type: String, required: true },
keywords: {type: String, initial:true, required: true, default:""},
description: {type: String},
state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'draft, published, archived', default: 'draft' },
author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User' },
createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
publishedAt: {type:Date,noedit:true},
content: { type: Types.Markdown}
});


News.defaultColumns = 'title, keywords, state|20%, author, publishedAt|15%'


News.schema.methods.isPublished = function() {
return this.state == 'published';
}

News.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
if (this.isModified('state') && this.isPublished() && !this.publishedAt) {
    this.publishedAt = new Date();
}
next();
});
News.register();
```

In my index.js, as part of the expose() method, I have the author populated:

**Index.js (fragment)**

```
...
    restful.expose({
    News : {
        populate:'author',
        methods: ['retrieve','list'],
        filter:{
            state:'published'
        },
        show:   ['title','author.name','keywords','publishedAt','description','content.html']
    },
 ...
```

My problem is that 'author.name' prints no value (it should return an object containing first and last name), and printing the author directly, includes fields such as as the author's id and password. Is there some way I get the fields I wanted from a related model without exposing everything in the call? I notice that content.html does return the HTML section of the Markdown element.